# How can I get a console readout at runtime in an application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, console

For debugging purposes, I'd like to access console printouts at runtime in a way similar to the Console app current on the App Store (that can be found [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/console/id317676250?mt=8)).

I did some searching of the docs and I can't find anything that's provided by Apple, but I feel like I'm missing something important.  Any insight?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do so using [`<asl.h>`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html). Here is an example that I threw together to create an array of console messages.

```
-(NSArray*)console
{
    NSMutableArray *consoleLog = [NSMutableArray array];

    aslclient client = asl_open(NULL, NULL, ASL_OPT_STDERR);

    aslmsg query = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);
    asl_set_query(query, ASL_KEY_MSG, NULL, ASL_QUERY_OP_NOT_EQUAL);
    aslresponse response = asl_search(client, query);

    asl_free(query);

    aslmsg message;
    while((message = asl_next(response)) != NULL)
    {
        const char *msg = asl_get(message, ASL_KEY_MSG);
        [consoleLog addObject:[NSString stringWithCString:msg encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    if (message != NULL) {
        asl_free(message);
    }
    asl_free(response);
    asl_close(client);

    return consoleLog;
}
```

Comment: While the console app made it into the app store I can not guarantee that future apps using `asl` will.

Comment: I understand.  This is for debugging only, and as such will be purposefully stripped from production-level code.

Comment: Well then use away, it will get the message, you can also use set_query to filter by severity, time etc, and you can use asl_get to get other values like severity, time etc.

Comment: Found an interesting note for IOS developers. The ASL implementation on the device will limit you to searching only the last 256 messages. Watch out for that one.

Comment: Marty... do you have to limit the query yourself? I occasionally get a crash when reading with ASL, but not sure what to attribute it to.

Comment: @BobSpryn there is currently no parameter to limit the number of results returned by the query. Google "asl manpage" to read the latest documentation as this may change. I too observed a crash when using the code snippet above, but I've since edited it to include a fix for a memory leak (aslmsg message must be freed if not NULL) which seems to have resolved the crashes.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is attached to Xcode, you can see console output (`NSLog`s and such) in the debug area:

[image]

If you're running the app and connecting to Xcode later, I believe you can get console logs in the Organizer.

---

Edit: to access the log file at runtime, you should try /var/log/system.log — but even better I recommend using a custom debug function, which would write to the system log and/or a text view in your app. (Check out NSLogv, which will be useful when writing a wrapper function.) This also has the advantage of letting you disable all debug logs from one place (just change your debug function).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm talking about access console output within an application at runtime, like the Console app that I linked in my question.

Comment: Think everybody should know how to use the debug log inside xCode