# How to put console outputs to a uitextview? Access to console logs

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, console, uitextview

i want to display a UITextView in my app, which should contain all outputs from console.

Is this possible? **How can i do that?**

i am asking that, because i want a "debug-feature" for special beta testers.

Comment: Can you not use a data store of some kind - array maybe.  So whenever you post to console you also add this into the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use to get console out put with answer at [getting console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150849/how-can-i-get-a-console-readout-at-runtime-in-an-application) and put output to UITextView

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this [Tutorial](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/) for getting the iOS logs.

```
aslmsg q, m;
int i;
const char *key, *val;

q = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);

aslresponse r = asl_search(NULL, q);
while (NULL != (m = aslresponse_next(r)))
{
    NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (i = 0; (NULL != (key = asl_key(m, i))); i++)
    {
        NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)key];

        val = asl_get(m, key);

        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:val];
        [tmpDict setObject:string forKey:keyString];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", tmpDict);
}
aslresponse_free(r);
```