# IOS10 print all the xcode console log onto a UITextview inside an iPhone app page

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, console, nslog

I want to print my Xcode console log into an UITextView inside one of my app pages.

And I want the log info can update in real time just like debugging the app when I connect my iPhone to the Xcode console.

Is there a way to do it?

I have checked few solutions
like: redirect NSlog to file which is an old fashion way.

Now in iOS10, apple is using Unified Logging and Activity Tracing
I watched the new video

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/

but I still have no idea how am I gonna do this?

Anyone can show me some sample objective-c code or swift code how to do this exactly?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I hope this will work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150849/how-can-i-get-a-console-readout-at-runtime-in-an-application

Comment: check this https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/logging?language=objc#symbols

Comment: In the last two minutes of Unified Logging and Activity Tracing wwdc video:

All of the ASL logging APIs are now superseded by these new APIs and, therefore, those old APIs are deprecated. There is an interesting edge case though. A new API for searching the log data is not going to be made public in this release. What that means is that there's no equivalent to asl_search functionality. If you absolutely depend on asl_search in your system, that may be a reason to wait for adopting the new logging system.          @DheerajD

Comment: @DheerajD ,so the method u mentioned is not working anymore for iOS10

Answer (score 1):

after 3days searching finally I found this works for me:

though it's in iOS10, but somehow this redirect still works

I don't really know why, but it finally works:

```
- (void)redirectLogToDocuments
{
    NSArray *allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [allPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathForLog = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFile.txt"];

    freopen([pathForLog cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
}
```

hope this will work for those people later need answer for this quesiton:)